# Shuffling a bunch of keys

Tags: algorithm, shuffle

This question primarily relates to a famous interview question of shuffling a pack of cards. I wandered through SO and found similar questions but the answers are mostly not up to the mark or they are ignored.

The question given was to build a function to shuffle the pack of cards.

**My solution:** This is possible if I put all the cards in a linked list in any order ( say sorted or unsorted - order doesn't matter). I generate a random number, take its mod to the current total number of cards and remove that index from the linked list to store the card in my shuffledArray.

This solution I think is great and it has the following running time:
O(n) for building the linked list in any order.
O(n) for removing it from the linked list.
O(1) for generating a random number each time.

So more or less we have a lower bound of O(n) for this algorithm.

What I am worried about is the space. The space taken at present is as follows:
1) O(n) for linked list
2) O(n) for shuffledArray.

Again a lower bound of O(n).

Can this be done in place ? I mean without using this n extra space.
Can it be done in time less than O(n) ?

Comment: In place would still be O(n), right?

Comment: Standard answer: [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle).

Comment: yeah, it would be but think of the n getting larger of the order 1,000,000 in this case n and 2n makes a difference

Comment: I don't understand. Why would anybody down vote my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) works inplace and does exactly n-1 random number generatings.

Comment: I am trying to understand this algorithm but its kind of going above my head.

Comment: Its the same as Andrew wrote, just going from the other end. You increase size, instead of decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

```
void shuffle(vector<T> v)
{
    int n = v.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        swap(v[i], v[i+rand(n-i)]);
};
```

Proof by induction:

1. a single element vector is trivially sorted
2. the first element is randomly selected, and by induction the remainder of the vector is shuffled

Comment: Oh! You answered before I did. :P

Answer (score -1):

How about iterating over the cards. On each step, you generate a random number between 1 and 52 and swap the current card with the card at this random number?

What do you think about that?

Comment: I might end up swapping same set of cards ;)

Comment: This uses more entropy than necessary.  You should only need N! random states to match the N! uniformly distributed candidate permutations.

Comment: Yes. I think Andrew's solution will work in that case. Or this Fisher-Yates thing as suggested by kiloataras

Comment: My solution is reverse Fisher-Yates, I find it more intuitive - they are exactly equivalent performance-wise.

Comment: I think there is also a bug with this solution, I will create another question.